# Openlayers 5.3 How to reload ImageWMS source to show updated data from server

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I created an openlayers map (version5.3). I added an ImageLayer, created an ImageWMS source to speak to an ArcGis server. The layer displays fine. I now need to refresh that layer every 30s.

I tried to use the refresh method https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_ImageWMS-ImageWMS.html#refresh but no luck. What I need is that the source reloads the url. But it simply does not do that.

I tried to add a parameter with a time stamp to the url, but ArcGis does not like that at all.

```
const wms_source =  new ImageWMS({
        url: 'https://my_secret_domain/arcgis/services/Project/TEST_Lightning/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetMap',
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        styles: 'default',
        params: {
            layers: '0',

        },

    })
    const lightning_layer =  new ImageLayer({


    })
lightning_layer.setSource(wms_source);
this.map = new Map({
        layers: [baseLayer, lightning_layer ],

        target: document.getElementById('lightning'),
        view: new View({

            center: fromLonLat([175.79, -37.79]),
            zoom: 7,
            projection: 'EPSG:3857'
        })
    });
// I would expect this to reload the source ...
// but looking into the debugger shows that it is not.
wms_source.refresh
```

Does anyone has an idea how to reload the source to show updated data from the server?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296358/openlayers-not-requesting-tiles-at-previously-visited-zoom-levels

Comment: Thanks for your comment JGH, I tried that - but still no change. If I change the URL more dramatically, say from https to http - then refresh reloads the layer. But not when using the time stamp method

Comment: Thanks again for your comment JGH, your comment helped me in the end. In pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to JGH's comment I worked out what I needed to change.

I did not add the timestemp to the initial set up of the source, but I added my interval function in which I update URL every 30s and then run refresh ...

```
setInterval(() => {
    wms_source.setUrl('https://my_top_secret_domain/Project/TEST_Lightning/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetMap&TIMESTAMP=' + new Date().getTime());
        this.wms_source.refresh();
    }, 30000); // 30s
```

That now works as expected